# Change div's hover state with jQuery timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I’m a complete jquery newb and I want to create 5 classes(.button1 - .button5) with a timer which toggles the next classes :hover or :active state every 4000ms on a continuous loop. I also want the ability for the timer to halt and continue if another one of the classes is hovered on by the user. Does anyone know of a good starting point or a thread with a similar solution?
I’ve attached a diagram.

[image]

CSS

```
.wrapper { width:100%; margin:0 auto; background:#f3f3f3; }
#buttonblock { display:block; }
.button1, .button2, .button3, .button4, .button5 { display:inline-block; margin:0 5px; height:50px; width:50px; border-radius:25px; background:#3cc8dd; }
.button1:hover, .button2:hover, .button3:hover, .button4:hover, .button5:hover{ background:#fbc040; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="buttonblock">
    <div class="button1"></div>
    <div class="button2"></div>
    <div class="button3"></div>
    <div class="button4"></div>
    <div class="button5"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var divs = $('#buttonblock').children('div'),
    number = divs.length,
    currentIndex = 0,
    intervalLength = 2000;

function setTimer() {
    divs.removeClass('hover');
    divs.eq(currentIndex).addClass('hover');
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex == number) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
}

setTimer();
var timer = setInterval(setTimer, intervalLength);

divs.mouseenter(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    divs.removeClass('hover');
    var div = $(this);
    div.addClass('hover');
    currentIndex = divs.index(div);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    timer = setInterval(setTimer, intervalLength);
});
```

[Example - setInterval](http://jsfiddle.net/G5LbA/6/)

[or using setTimeout](http://jsfiddle.net/G5LbA/13/)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply loop over the array of objects, for example

```
var $block = $('#buttonblock div');

for (var n=0; n<$block.length; n++)
{
    var domELM = $block[n]; // you can do $(domELM) to create a jquery of the dom
    // do stuff here, set interval or whatever it is you wish to do.
    if(n == $block.elngth)
    n=0; //resets the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="buttonblock">
    <div class="button button1"></div>
    <div class="button button2"></div>
    <div class="button button3"></div>
    <div class="button button4"></div>
    <div class="button button5"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.hover {
 background:#fbc040;
}
```

js

```
var counter = 1;
var timer;
$(document).ready(function () {
 startTimer();
 $('.button').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.hover').removeClass('hover');
    clearInterval(timer);
 });

 $('.button').mouseleave(function () {
    startTimer();
 });
});

function startTimer() {
 timer = setInterval(function () {
  counter = (counter > 5) ? 1 : counter;
  $('.hover').removeClass('hover');
  $('.button' + counter).addClass('hover');
  counter++;
 }, 4000);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96Ar9/)